# Ionic 2: Cannot find name 'SQLite'

Tags: sqlite, ionic2

I'm trying to use SQLite on an Ionic 2 project

```
ionic start App_One blank --v2 --ts
```

Then I install the platform:

```
ionic platform add android
ionic platform add ios
```

Then SQLite plugin:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage --save
```

But when I try to initialize my provider as follows:

```
ionic g provider db-service
```

Then

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SQLite } from 'ionic-native';

@Injectable()
export class DbService {

  db: SQLite = null;

  constructor() {
    console.log('Hello DbService Provider');
    this.db = new SQLite();
  }

}
```

I have the following error: "Cannot find name 'SQLite'"

I have try:

```
npm install
ionic state restore
```

Any idea?

Thx

Info:

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0

Ionic Framework Version: 2.3.0

Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1

Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0

Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.4

ios-deploy version: Not installed

ios-sim version: Not installed

OS: Linux 4.4

Node Version: v7.8.0

Xcode version: Not installed

Comment: Can you follow steps on this [link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/) and [link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite/)  and see what happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stopped giving problems installing and changing the following fragment:

Dependency:

```
sudo npm install --save @ionic-native/core@latest
sudo npm install --save @ionic-native/sqlite
ionic plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage --save
sudo npm install --save @ionic/storage
```

Fragment:

```
import {SQLite} from '@ionic-native/sqlite';

@Injectable()

export class DBService {
    db = null;
    constructor () {
        this.db = new SQLite ();
    }
...
}
```

The fragment is initialize db in null and let the constructor take care of instantiating SQLite.

Comment: elegant answer.